# Cube vs. Micro Cube in BusinessObjects

Tags: business-objects

I am having problems understanding cubes and microcubes in BusinessObjects environment.
Although I have tried to find answers online, I did not find an answers that give overall explanations.
Beside description of the functionality, I would like to know where is cube and where is micro cube located: on server or in browser?
How many cubes/microcubes are there? One microcube per report or one micro cube per session, or sthg else?

Furthermore, can anyone explain the difference in aggregations on database level as opossed to aggregation on report level (when defining a measure, there are two possibilities - to define aggregation on report and/or aggregation level). Although there are some answers online, they are too general. Therefore, I would appreciate a simple explanation with an example.

And finaly, is it possible to color tables in data foundation layer? (since I have a lot of tables in a universe, it would be very helpful if I could color fact and dimensional tables).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It helps to understand the two-pass nature of querying traditional (non-OLAP) data in BO.  When you refresh a report in BO, the report engine constructs a SQL statement based on the objects (results and conditions) that are specified in the query.

The SQL statement is sent to the database, and the report engine then retrieves the data that is returned from the database.  This data becomes the *microcube* -- it is nothing more than a tabular representation of the data that was received from the database.  If you could look at it visually, it would look identical to what you would get by running the SQL statement in a traditional SQL tool (such as TOAD or SQL*Plus).

The microcube then becomes the source for the report presentation.  Your could, for example, create a table in a report by dragging in dimensions and measures from the object list.  As you are dragging in these objects, the table will recalculate and redisplay as appropriate.  This is all done by retrieving and calculating the data from the *microcube*, **not** from the source data.  That is, as you are interacting with a report tab, you are not initiating a refresh from the database -- all of the calculation is done from the microcube.

For example, let's say you have created a new query with two dimensions (State, Region) and one measure (Sales).  The SQL might look like this:

```
select state_nm,region_nm,sum(sales_amt)
  from all_sales
 group by state_nm,region_nm
```

Note that there is a sum() applied to sales_amt.  This is causing the database to perform the initial aggregation on this field.

The microcube that is created after the refresh may look like:

```
AL    North     30000
AL    South     40000
AR    North      5000
AR    South     10000
```

Now you create a table in your report, and select just State and Sales.  The report engine uses the data in the microcube to display the result:

```
AL     70000
AR      5000
```

In this case, the BO report engine has performed a sum() aggregation on Sales Amt.  This is report-side aggregation.

Then you remove State.  Again, the report engine aggregates the table from the microcube, not the database:

```
75000
```

The microcube is stored with the report file.  If you are working with a WebI report via InfoView, then the microcube is loaded into the server's memory.  When you save the report, a physical file is created on the server (with a .wid extension); the microcube is stored in that file.  If you open the report again, the microcube is again loaded into the server's memory and is available for interaction.

If you are using Rich Client, then the same behavior applies, it's just using your workstation and local storage.

The term "cube" is generally used to describe data sources in an OLAP environment (SSAS or Essbase, for example).  This is *external* to BO -- BO would be querying data *from* an OLAP cube.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the **aggregation**:

- **Database aggregation** is performed by your RDBMS on the source data, *before* it is transferred to the client application (e.g. Web Intelligence). You can apply database aggregation by using a statement such as `SUM()` or `COUNT()` in the select statement of your measure (in the business layer of your universe). It only makes sense for measures objects, not dimensions.

  - Changes the data retrieved from the database
  - Can have a positive impact on performance due to a small dataset being returned
  - Leverages the database aggregate performance

.

- **Projection aggregation** or **report aggregation** is the aggregation performed by the client application (e.g. Web Intelligence) *after* retrieving the data from the database, thus in-memory.

  - Happens on the fly as the dimensions change to which the measure is projected (hence projection aggregation)
  - The result set retrieved from the database remains the same

---

Regarding the **table colours**: have a look at the tutorial *[Apply color to tables that share the same information](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-22086)*. This should show you how to configure the colours for the tables in the data foundation.

Comment: Great tutorial Kristof! Thanks.
However, although I followed every step in the tutorial, my tables were not colored. It the moment when I select few tables and click on "Families" and select a family I have previously created, the selected tables do not change color. Any idea why is this happening?
Is there some additional setting I have to change?

Comment: by the way - I am working in "Master View". -> Is it possible to color tables in Master View?

Comment: @Adam It should work as demonstrated in the tutorial, regardless of the view. Can you check in the main interface (after defining the families) if you can apply the color/family in the drop down in the toolbar? FYI: I did notice in the past that setting the color in one view did not result in the same color being set in a different view. That can be seen as an annoyance or a benefit, depending on your situation.

Comment: here is the screenshot http://tinypic.com/r/28vaxch/8
 After I define the family and try to apply it on a table in data foundation document, nothing happens. I am working with BO 4.1 which is even more strange...

Comment: @Adam I've had issues in 4.1 SP3 as well with applying table families (I could create one, but I couldn't select it from the list), so it could be a bug you're experiencing. I have used the feature successfully in previous versions though. Keep a look out for a fix in the release notes of future versions of create an incident with SAP Support to confirm that this is indeed an issue and to have an idea when it will be fixed.

Comment: @Adam Noticed the same behaviour today on 4.1 SP3. Nothing happened after selecting the table family, until I saved the DF, closed it and then reopened it. So definitely a bug.

Comment: I tried it now - and it works. Maybe it works only on fridays :) SAP people obviously have a sense of humor :)

Comment: maybe of the topic, but I still have to ask you. The problem I am facing with is this: how to recognize when to create a fact table. Can you please give me your opinion and suggestion on this and recommend some good references that tackle this topic - the references that deal precisely with this topic, without too much theorizing.